# Class Declarations, Constructors and toString methods for all the classes

Tags: java, class, testing, constructor, tostring

Question:
Implement a super class Person. Make two classes, Student and Instructor
that inherit from Person. A person has a name and a year of birth. A student
has major and the instructor has a salary. Write the class declarations, the
constructors, and the methods to String for all classes. Write a test program
that tests these classes and methods.

This may not be a complicated one but i'm a beginner in java. Please help me.
I'm getting the following error at the both the constructors 'student()' and 'instructor()'.

```
"constructor Person in class Person cannot be applied to given types;
  required: String,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length."
```

Here's my code:

```
package One;

class Person{
    String name;
    int yob;

    Person(String s, int d){
        name = s;
        yob = d;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Name: "+name+"\n Year of Birth: "+yob;
    }
}
class Student extends Person{
    String major;

    Student(String s){
        major = s;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "The student did his majors in "+major;
    }
}
class Instructor extends Person{
    int salary; 

    Instructor(int a){
        salary = a;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("The salary is ",salary);
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p = new Person("Stephen", 1991);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to implement a constructor with no arguments in Person class `Person(){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the classes `Student` and `Instructor` derive from `Person`. This means that any constructor parameters needed by the base class are also needed by the derived class. When you create a `Student`, how will the compiler know what to put in the parameters of the `Person` constructor?

So the code should be like this:

```
// Student constructor
Student(String majorParam, String nameParam, int yobParam)
{
    super(nameParam, yobParam);
    this.major = majorParam;
}

...

// Similarly, Instructor constructor
Instructor(int salaryParam, String nameParam, int yobParam)
{
    super(nameParam, yobParam);
    salary = salaryParam;
}
```

Notice how we are transferring the constructor parameters required by the base class `Person` using the `super` constructor keyword. This always has to be the first line in the derived class constructor.

Then you can construct `Student` and `Instructor` as:

```
Student s = new Student("TheMajor", "TheName", 42);

Instructor i = new Instructor(1000, "TheName", 42);
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I'm reading the post to learn as well. Which language was the earlier answer for? C++?

Answer (score 0):

There is no empty constructor in Person class, so you have to create that and it should work perfectly. Don't forget that super() is called by default unless explicitly called.